# How can I install common-lisp on jupyter notebook from linux?

Tags: anaconda, common-lisp, jupyter-notebook

I had a professor whose has a web-server with common-lisp notebooks in Jupyter Notebook. I want to install it in my Linux, but I don't know how.

Any sugestion?

Comment: Cl-Jupyter? Google for that in github

Comment: You mean [cl-notebook](https://github.com/inaimathi/cl-notebook)? Seems like you can install your favorite CL and install it using the readme that is shown on the first page.

Answer (score 1):

I understood the question as: "How can I use jupyter-notebook for common-lisp code". If this a wrong interpretation please comment so I can delete my answer.

> Kernels (Programming Languages) The Jupyter team maintains the IPython
>   kernel since the Jupyter notebook server depends on the IPython kernel
>   functionality. Many other languages, in addition to Python, may be
>   used in the notebook.
>
> The community maintains many other language kernels, and new kernels
>   become available often. Please see the list of available kernels for
>   additional languages and kernel installation instructions to begin
>   using these language kernels [[1](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/kernels.html)].

Thus you have to look up the common-lisp kernel you want to use [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) and it seems like the only option available is [cl-jupyter](https://github.com/fredokun/cl-jupyter/blob/master/about-cl-jupyter.ipynb). The corresponding github project has the installation guide contained [here](https://github.com/fredokun/cl-jupyter).

As a small side note: If you are only looking for a good interactive environment to program common-lisp in have a look at [emacs-slime](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/). I have yet to find a more seamless programming environment for common-lisp.